# Chromium fetching all my favicons all the time

Tags: angularjs, chromium, favicon

When using *chromium*, in my *angularjs* application, when I click on *any* link, *all* my favicons get loaded.

My main HTML page contains 10 lines like

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-57x57.png" sizes="57x57">
```

with size going up to `192x192`. This might be wrong as it's just an "adaptation of something I found somewhere".

However it doesn't explain, why all of them get loaded every time, does it? All the links just change the URL after the hashbang and usually lead to no server request at all, *apart from fetching 10 favicons.*

Even if I did everything wrong, the favicon is global for the whole site, so there's no need to reload it, right?

With a little fiddling with the headers I can serve them with any of `200 OK` or `304 NOT MODIFIED` or `200 OK (from cache)`, but whatever I do, they *all always* get requested.

This doesn't happen in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

What you described is a [known issue of Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820), related to the fact that [Chrome doesn't support the `sizes` attribute](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112941).

[Firefox also used to be impacted](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712), and it still doesn't support `sizes`. However, it doesn't load all icons anymore. As far as I know, this is not documented anywhere. This may have been fixed as a side effect.

There is no "solution" but a workaround: declare less icons. I suggest you to use this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). The [generated images and HTML were designed with this issue in mind](http://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/new-favicon-package-less-is-more/). For example, it does't generate the 192x192 PNG icon by default, because Android Chrome (the browser it is dedicated to) primarily uses the Webb App manifest. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.

Comment: Loading all of them is understandable as a consequence of not understanding the `size` attribute. However, they do get loaded on every URL change (no page reload), *is this related*, too? +++ My application is meant for desktop only (there's an app, too), should I still use the generator? +++ How does the generator prevent the issue?

Comment: This is not what I observe. When I navigate to an already visited page, Chrome doesn't reload the icons +++ I would say your favicon should reflect your site. For example if your site is responsive, it should have icons for mobile. +++ The generator used to generate a lot of pictures (and all the other services copied the package to they do generate a lot of pics right now). It was redesigned to create less images. Nothing fancy!